# optimizing chat box in php and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a chat box using jQuery and php.

```
setInterval(
    function(){

        if($('#session_container').children().length > 0){
            if(localStorage['group_id']){
                var group_id = localStorage['group_id'];
                var session_id = localStorage['session_id'];
                var gsid = 'GSID' + group_id + session_id;
                $('#chatbox').load('php/chatbox.php', {'group_id' : group_id, 'session_id' : session_id}, 
                    function(){
                        $('#chatbox').find('tr:even').addClass('alt');
                        if($('#chatbox').children().length == 0){
                            localStorage.clear();
                            window.location.replace('chatro_main.php');
                        }
                    }
                );
            }else{

            }
        }
    }, 1000);
```

As you can see from the code above, the script runs every one second which I think is very aggressive and I think it's also wasting power(my laptop's battery seems to be draining faster when I was running this). Is there a better way of doing this. Something like not reloading the content while the user is on another tab on the browser window. Or something like updating only the content if another user sent a message? 
If you know of another technology that could do this in a more optimal way, you could also mention it.

Comment: [HTML5 WebSockets](http://weevilgenius.net/2010/10/html-5-websocket-chat-demo/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible answers to this question:

1. Don't use `setInterval`, but repeatedly `setTimeout` and adjust your timeout. The idea is, that you first try like every 10 seconds, and then increase the time, if there is no action. So the intervals would be: 10, 20, 40, *message received*, 10, 20, *message received*, 10, ... You have to adjust the factor you will actually increase the timeout to fit your needs.
2. Implement it using WebSockets (see comment of @Christian Varga)
3. Use node.js as server side language, which interacts with client side javascript pretty well. You can have node.js broadcast messages to all clients, so you actually have a two-way connection there (I think they use WebSockets and as fallback something like comet.js, but I am not sure, I just saw it done once)

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not an answer but i can't make a comment cause of my rep. I had a chat like this, but i had a var named chatState, when chatState is 1(or true) fires interval for every second when no msg received for a while chatSate goes for 0(false) and clears that interval and starts a new one checks for every 10 seconds if there is someone type anything to chat? Not sure this is a good way but i tought that would be better for server cause less request, but as i said not sure is this a good way so this is would be a comment instead of answer.